# Pytest, How to do test against either fixture's value or None?

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest

I have one *test-case* with one *fixture*:

```
@pytest.fixture
def user(test_client):
    return User.objects.first()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('content', ['nice post',])
def test_post(test_client, user, content):
    reponse = test_client.post(
        '/api/v1.0/posts', 
        json={
            'content': content,
            'author': user,
        },
        follow_redirects=True
    )

    assert reponse.status_code == 200
```

But I want in addition to testing against some `User` object, to test against `None` (I expect test to fail for None). I thought I could do something like:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def User_or_null(test_client, request):
    if request.param:
        return User.objects.first()
    else:
        return None
```

But I do not think this will allow me to mark the test case with `pytest.mark.xfail` for `None` value? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem with parametrizing the `user` fixture. You can mark separate parameters via [`pytest.param`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-param), for example:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    'testuser',
    # wrap None into pytest.param to treat it specially
    pytest.param(None, marks=pytest.mark.xfail)
])
def user(request):
    if request.param is None:
        return None
    return User.objects.filter(name=request.param).first()  # or whatever
```

However, this would mean that all tests using the `user` fixture will xfail/xpass on `None` - this may be not something you want for all tests. Use indirect parametrization if you want to xfail only selected test:

```
# user fixture is not parametrized now

@pytest.fixture
def user(request):
    if request.param is None:
        return None
    return User.objects.filter(name=request.param).first()

# instead, parametrizing is done from the test:

@pytest.mark.parametrize('content', ['nice post',])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('user', [
    'testuser',
    pytest.param(None, marks=pytest.mark.xfail
)], indirect=True)
def test_post(test_client, user, content):
    ...
```